# Tabstrip inside template of Kendo Scheduler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler, kendo-tabstrip

I create a view that contains a kendo scheduler, and when i create a template for add event and I add a tabstrip, it does not compile and I have a bug

MyView

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<MeetingViewModel>()
    .Name("scheduler")
    .Date(new DateTime(2016, 4, 01))
    .StartTime(new DateTime(2016, 4, 01, 00, 00, 00))
    .Height(600)
    .Views(views => {
        views.DayView();
        views.WeekView(weekView => weekView.Selected(true));
        views.MonthView();
        views.AgendaView();
    })
    .Editable(editable => {
        editable.TemplateName("EditMeeting");
    })
    .Timezone("Etc/UTC")
   .Events(e=>e.Edit("scheduleEdit"))
    .DataSource(d => d
        .Model(m => {
            m.Id(f => f.IDMeeting);
            m.Field(f => f.NumMeeting).DefaultValue("No title");
        })
        .Events(e => e.Error("error_handler"))
        .Read("Meeting_Read", "Meeting")
        .Create("Meeting_Create", "Meeting")
        .Destroy("Meeting_Destroy", "Meeting")
        .Update("Meeting_Update", "Meeting")
    )
)
```

my template EditMeeting

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
          .Name("tabstrip")

          .Items(tabstrip =>
          {
              tabstrip.Add().Text("Générale").Selected(true).Content(@<text>
<label>test</label>
</text>);

}
)
)
```

the error

```
kendo.all.min.js:9 Uncaught Error: Invalid template:'<div class="k-widget k-tabstrip k-header" id="tabstrip"><ul class="k-reset k-tabstrip-items">
<li class="k-item k-state-default k-state-active"><a class="k-link" href="#tabstrip-1">G&\\#233;n&\\#233;rale</a></li></ul><div class="k-content k-state-active" id="tabstrip-1" style="display:block"></div></div><script> 

jQuery(function(){jQuery("\#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({});});</script>' Generated code:'var o,e=kendo.htmlEncode;with(data){o='<div class="k-widget k-tabstrip k-header" id="tabstrip"><ul class="k-reset k-tabstrip-items"><li class="k-item k-state-default k-state-active"><a class="k-link" href="';tabstrip-1">G&\#233;n&\#233;rale</a></li></ul><div class="k-content k-state-active" id="tabstrip-1" style="display:block"></div></div><script>   jQuery(function(){jQuery("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({});});</script>;o+=;}return o;'
```